# how do you access docker labels from fluentd

Tags: docker, fluentd, grafana-loki

I'm trying to get stdout/stderr from my docker containers into `loki`. I have the basics working but I'd like to populate a loki field with a tag called `client` that's defined in my `docker-compose.yaml`.

relevant section of my `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
  x-logging-defaults: &logging_defaults
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: 10.10.10.1:24224
        tag: docker.application
        labels: "client=the-client"     # here?
    labels:
      - client=the-client              # or here?
```

section of `fluent.conf`

```xml
<filter docker.**>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    hostname "#{Socket.gethostname}"

    # I think magic goes here, I've tried many variations
    # of the following examples
    client $.client
    client $.docker.label.client      
    client ${ record.dig("labels", "client") }
  </record>
</filter>

<match docker.**>
    @type loki
    url "http://loki.service.consul:3100"
    <label>
        client $.client   # more magic here?
    </label>
    extra_labels {
        "client": "or maybe here?"
    }
</match>
```

Comment: Try: `client ${ record["labels"] }` with `enable_ruby true`. See: https://docs.fluentd.org/filter/record_transformer#enable_ruby. Otherwise, can you try and dump `record` on STDOUT to check its contents? Also, do check if there are error logs.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately that's not working either. After doing a `tcpdump` it appears that docker is not sending the labels to fluentd at all, so this was never going to work. I'm keeping this open for now in case I get everything sorted.

Comment: I give up, I just added the client to the end of the tag since that is sent. `docker.app.acme-client` and then `client ${tag_parts[2]}`

Comment: @Kurt do you need something like this plugin? [docker-metadata](https://github.com/fabric8io/fluent-plugin-docker_metadata_filter)

Comment: @AliMalek maybe but https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/fluentd/#labels-env-and-env-regex implies it should "just work". I had looked at that plugin and another that was still maintained but couldn't get it to work either. Sad pandas all around.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes to the initial configuration with comments:

```
 x-logging-defaults: &logging_defaults
    logging:
      driver: "fluentd"
      options:
        fluentd-address: 10.10.10.1:24224
        tag: docker.application
        labels: "client" # In this section, you have to specify the allowed labels, that will be passed to the LogEntry.
    labels:
      - client=the-client
```